# Firebase null pointer exception

Tags: android, firebase, null-pointer

I am getting null pointer exception in firebase I knows that there is not any value like that to which database reference I am giving but I wants that when the value is generated then it will be shown automatically...
Just wants to get that single value everytime it is created on the firebase but its giving me null pointer exception on the line String val =.....

Please help me ...

```
final DatabaseReference dtt = database.getReference("/trial/trials/");
    dtt.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String val= dataSnapshot.child("myvalue").getValue().toString();
            if(val!=null)
            {
                Log.e("not null------","---------------");
            }else
            {
                Log.e("null------","---------------");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Please help me.....Please ..

Comment: Just a guess because we don't have much information to go off of here but `dataSnapshot.child("myvalue")` is probably the culprit...

Comment: Yaa can you suggest me somthing by which I cant get null pointer exception please

Comment: I have tried by removing child and directly giving it in the reference Still getting error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using getValue() in wrong way. Should be

```
String val= dataSnapshot.child("myvalue").getValue(String.class);
```

To check, if value exists you can convert dataSnapshot to Hashmap, like this

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
String val= hashmap.get("myvalue");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
final DatabaseReference dtt = database.getReference("/trial/trials/");
dtt.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String val= dataSnapshot.child("myvalue").getValue(String.class);
        if(val!=null)
        {
            Log.e("not null------","---------------");
        }else
        {
            Log.e("null------","---------------");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```